# Manual acknowledgments in Node.js using node-amqp module

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using the module [node-amqp](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp) by postwait.

I am able to publish/subscribe to a queue some messages, but I would like to acknowledge the messages manually.

For example, I want the message to be read, and not acknowledged, then to execute some calculation on this message, and THEN send a `q.shift()` to acknowledge the message and go through the second message.

I want the acknowledges to be manually used.

Actually I have a function which permits to subscribe with the flag `{ack: false}`
then I have a function to manually make a `q.shift()` (as said in the doc).

But when I publish 2 messages, and then I read 2 messages, without acknowledging, I see the 2 messages. But I would like the subrscribe to repeat the same message that was received at first, until I didn't acknowledge it.

How can I use the methods ?

Answer (score 1):

i know this question is kind of old, just saw it when i was searching for a problem

you have to set the "ack-flag" to true, just to make sure that you manually acknowledge the message. ack: false means the acknowledge will be done automatically

```
queue.subscribe({ack: true}, ...
```